# Sprite Kit Particle Emitter Clear Background & Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have placed some images and buttons on a storyboard connected to my view with a Particle Emitter on a SKView. The problem is that no matter how many places I set the background color to clearColor the background appears to be black and I cannot see the elements on my storyboard. With Particle Emitters can you use the storyboard?

```
SKView *skView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    skView.backgroundColor = [SKColor clearColor];


    SKScene *scene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
    scene.backgroundColor = [SKColor clearColor];

    // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
    [skView presentScene:scene];

    NSString *myParticlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"snowParticle" ofType:@"sks"];
    SKEmitterNode *snowParticle = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:myParticlePath];
    snowParticle.particlePosition = CGPointMake(0, 568);


    [scene addChild:snowParticle];

    [self.view addSubview:skView];
```

Thanks,

Comment: SKView's cannot be set to a clearColor. There was a conversation about this perviously on another post (I can't find it at the moment). I'd wait for @learnCocos2D to see this question to explain why.

Comment: so I would have to manually add the background and the other elements on top of the SKView but underneath the particle?

Comment: Well, the background first, particle second, other elements after.